# How to get links in Excel to open in single browser tab

Tags: html, perl, excel, hyperlink, target

I have an Excel spreadsheet with html links in one column. The links are being generated by a perl script via `Win32::OLE` like so (inside a loop with index $i):

```
my $range = $Sheet->Range("B".$row);
my $link = "http://foobar.com/show.pl?id=$i";
$Sheet->Hyperlinks->Add({Anchor=>$range,Address=>$link,TextToDisplay=>"Link to $i"});
```

Currently, every time I click one of these links, it opens in a new browser tab.  Since there are a lot of these links I wind up with 20 tabs after working with the sheet for a while.  This is a pain in the behind because I periodically have to go through and close them.

Is there some way to get these links to open in the same browser tab? I don't know if it's possible to specify the HTML equivalent of an anchor target with a constant name using the `Hyperlinks->Add` method, or if this would even do the job.

Comment: From reading around, it seems that the default behaviour for ShellExecute, when opening an URL in Explorer, is to replace the current page. Maybe you could try a different format for the hyperlink target, calling something like `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,ShellExecute`...

Comment: Yeah question is how to do that from the Excel object model that's invoked by Perl Win32.  Seems like it should be possible to specify a target for a link and just give all the links the same target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which browser you are using:

For Firefox, see this link [Force Firefox To Open Links In Same Tab](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/07/03/force-firefox-to-open-links-in-same-tab/)

Requires setting option in `about:config` `browser.link.open_newwindow = 1`

For IE, `Tools/options/General/Tabs/Setings`

```
Open links from other programs in: The current Tab or Window
```

Comment: I also think that managing tabs is more of browser's task and I would go nuts if someone managed to override browser behavior I configured. I also work with a spreadsheet w/links and open about the same number of tabs and it's allright. Besides, there is a 'close other tabs' option in firefox.

Comment: That's a possible solution but I really only want to change the behavior for this task, and if I understand it correctly these changes are global.

Answer (score 1):

Try using  [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

# Create a new workbook called simple.xls and add a worksheet
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('Example.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# The general syntax is write($row, $column, $token). Note that row and
# column are zero indexed
# Write a hyperlink
$worksheet->write(10, 0, 'http://perldoc.perl.org/');
$worksheet->write(11, 0, 'http://stackoverflow.com/');

__END__
```

the hyperlinks are opened in same browser tabs(works fine in IE,Firefox,Chrome)

Comment: For me, links open in separate tabs.  Nice perl mod tho, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the docs for the Excel object model, and there are no properties of a hyperlink that would indicate this is possible.  Thanks for the come-backs tho.